# Как правильно составить JOIN запрос MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы MySQL: `cs_lots` и `cs_lots_history`. Связаны ID->ID_LOT

[image: Таблица cs_lots_history]

[image: Таблица cs_lots]

Нужно написать запрос, который будет выводить ID каждого лота из `cs_lots` в массив, а так же user_personaname из `cs_lots_history` если ID=ID_LOT

Запрос, который уже удалось сочинить:

```sql
SELECT
    cs_lots_history.*,
    cs_lots.id as csid,
    inv_id,
    inv_assets,
    inv_image,
    inv_color,
    inv_name,
    inv_rarity,
    inv_type,
    inv_price,
    price_ticket,
    places,
    now_places
FROM cs_lots
LEFT JOIN cs_lots_history
  ON cs_lots.id = cs_lots_history.id_lot
WHERE active_lot='1'
  AND user_personaname='@Saundefined'
GROUP BY cs_lots.id;
```

Но дело в том, что он выводит только 6 лотов, т.к. в таблице `cs_lots_history` у ника `@Saundefined` всего 6 покупок (уникальных id_lot). А если их вообще не будет, то результат и вовсе не выведется.

Если же сделать без ника запрос, то выведет все 12 лотов, но тогда смысла от запроса нет, т.к. в массив не попадет купленная вещь этим пользователем.

Как сделать, чтобы выводило все 12 лотов ориентируясь на `cs_lots` и при этом, если ник не найден в `cs_lots_history` с `id`=`id_lot`, то тогда выводить просто в столбик значение NULL.

Comment: Попробуйте запрос запрос делать к таблице `cs_lots_history`, а через `LEFt JOIN` подключать `cs_lots`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой-то странный у Вас вопрос. Не до конца понятно, в каком случае такое может понадобиться. Т.е. скорее всего Вы не совсем корректно решаете свою проблему. Более того еще и немного странно запрос пишете =)

Но тем не менее, если Вы хотите вывести все активные лоты с базы, но при этом показать также только историю по нужному нику, тогда что-то вроде этого должно быть:

```sql
SELECT l.*, lh.*
FROM cs_lots l
LEFT JOIN cs_lots_history lh ON l.id = lh.id_lot AND
    lh.user_personaname='@Saundefined'
WHERE l.active_lot='1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Замените

`WHERE` на `AND`

и

`GROUP` на `ORDER`

[Внешние соединения](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_these_sly_outer_joins.html)

Comment: А что значит `WHERE` на `AND`? Запрос без `WHERE` ведь вызовет синтаксическую ошибку

Comment: Я иногда пишу запросы без FROM. И ничего. Главное - подход знать.

Comment: @jekaby SQL запрос без предиката (WHERE) никогда не вызовет синтаксическую ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое @msi и особенно большое @Aries.

Ответ на вопрос оказался простым. Сделал таким образом:

```
$res2 = mysql_query("select cs_lots.*, cs_lots.id as csid, h.*, h.id_lot as chid_lot from cs_lots left join cs_lots_history=h on cs_lots.id=h.id_lot and h.user_steamid='".$_SESSION['steamid']."' where cs_lots.active_lot=1 group by cs_lots.id") or die(mysql_error());
```

Дурачек еще просто, ничего не скажешь.. :)